# How do you control voltage to a BLDC motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I'm new at this and all but, how do you control the voltage going to an electrical BLDC motor? I want to control the voltage going to a motor on a dial that goes from 0-100%
Thanks

Comment: Control of BLDC motors is quite complex and not something you are going to achieve based on what would fit in an answer here.  Realistically you need a pre-made BLDC driver, perhaps (for some motors) an RC hobby "ESC".  Typically you do not control the voltage independently, but rather command speed or effort from the driver.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is done with PWM (Pulse Width Modulation). PWM alternately applies full supply voltage or zero volts to the motor, with an on/off ratio of 0-100%. The PWM frequency is set high enough (eg. 8 kHz) that the motor responds to the average voltage.

How this is controlled depends on the BLDC controller type. A 'Hobby' ESC (Electronic Speed Controller) typically accepts the same signal as 'hobby' servos - a pulse between 1 and 2 ms (representing 0-100% PWM or 'throttle') repeated every 20 ms. This signal can be generated with a [servo tester](http://www.drivecalc.de/circuits/Servotester.html).

Industrial controllers may have a 0-5 V or 0-10 V analog input (which can be created with a [potentiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer)), or some digital communication protocol such as I<sup>2</sup>C or RS232, which might be generated by a computer or MCU (microcontroller).